# GWT Properties file configuration

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am new to GWT, and facing one problem.

How we have .properties file for initial configuration at startup.
I want to create one in GWT App.

Also, GWT has client and server package.

I want to setup the configuration at client package because all configuration belongs to client side.

My actual need,

I have one textArea which takes up only fixed number of characters and length is defined in my properties file like below.

So I have to read a properties file for validation.

my.properties

```
smsConstraintEnabled=true
smsConstraintCharLimit=160
```

I found few link but all are talking about properties file regarding Locale, I don't have any need on Locale side but need simple key-value configuration.

I want this file to be loaded at startup or at Entry point itself and then I can use it at any client package classes for my validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Constants` interface. It's built with I18N in mind but will work just as well in this case, where you provide the constant values for a single locale, the default one (therefore used for every locale you'll compile your app with).

That however means the file is *read* at compile-time, not runtime (i.e. you'll have to recompile your app each time you change the properties file).

If you want something more *dynamic*, then read the file on the server-side and pass the information to the client-side. Easiest, and with minimal overhead, is to use a *[dynamic host page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page)*. To *read* the values in your client code, then either use a `Dictionary` (and `Integer.parseInt` et al.) or use [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) (possibly with an [overlay type](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay)).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, actually i was confused what to do as every site gives example considering i18n as need, so i was just thinking that was not my need. i did with Constants interface and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Also is it mandatory to have the properties file name and interface name to be same? also can you describe this lines in detail "where you provide the constant values for a single locale, the default one (therefore used for every locale you'll compile your app with)."

Comment: The file names must match, this is how GWT finds the properties file when generating an implementation class for the interface. And I meant that if you provide only a `MyConstants.properties` (no specified locale == default locale) and no `MyConstants_en.properties` (or some other locale), then that single file will be used whichever the locale of your app.